# No varnish headers

Tags: magento2.2, nginx, varnish

I install varnish(5) just like here:  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

I make test from varnish cli

```
varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

start
Debug: Child (26063) Started
200 0

Info: Child (26063) said Child starts
```

Everything looks ok.

But when I try run curl test:

```
curl -I -v --location-trusted 'https://mymagento.com'
```

I don't see any varnish headers.

How can I debug this problem? Or where can I look for some tips?

Answer (score 1):

**X-Magento-Debug is from varnish.**

If you read the vcl file, you will see X-Magento-Debug there. It will change to **X-Magento-Cache-Debug** once you're in **production mode**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Varnish header request only displays in **developer** mode. [Click Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html)

**First, make sure you are using Magento’s developer mode; otherwise, you won’t see the headers.**

2. Make sure the varnish cache set in the backend as a full-page cache in **store -> configuration -> advanced -> full page cache**

Comment: Yes, I know. I don't see headers in developer mode :). I see others Magento headers like `X-Magento-Debug: 1` but not those from varnish.

Comment: if possible, please paste the results.

Comment: @Maciej, do you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**My Response headers are give below:**

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 09:21:19 GMT
Expires: Mon, 08 May 2017 09:20:52 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Set-Cookie: form_key=HfXDuOKLNlnRkV3x; expires=Tue, 08-May-2018 10:20:52 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=s72hj0entb9avq6f8vtkt53bcu; expires=Tue, 08-May-2018 10:20:52 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Magento-Debug: 1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this section in /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
sub vcl_deliver
```

You'll notice that some headers were unset e.g.

```
unset resp.http.X-Varnish
unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
```

Comment them out if you want to see them in the response headers.

Also make sure that you set your Magento 2 environment to 'developer'